# How to add legend in Qgis2Web plugin while exporting maps?

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

currently i am working with the publishing web maps with the Qgis2web plugin. but i didn't find any kind of legend window or event to add legend. Is there any other source to add Legend?below is snapshot of Qgis2Web parameters window. there i didn't find any event to add legend.[image]

I need to display my all legend. e.g 
[image]
to the final web map. suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Add layers list" is the option. You have it checked in the screenshot above. For Leaflet maps, it adds layer names and icons. For OpenLayers3 maps, it just adds the layer names. Is that what you need, or do you need more? If more, can you describe what you need?

Comment: i attach new screen shot. what i exactly want. Add layer list only add the layer list and elements. It doesn't add the legend, classification, color templates etc details. So i need all this details along with layer list.

Comment: Are you using Openlayers 3 or Leaflet format? Try Leaflet. That adds your categories/ranges.

Comment: i tried leaflet also but it giving me python error while exporting the maps.

Comment: Please open an issue on Github so I can investigate the python error message. Do try downloading the master branch from Github as well. If you have non-ASCII layer names, that has only just been fixed in master.